# SuiteCRM - unable to login - session has expired

Tags: session, nginx

I migrated from apache to nginx. Everything is working fine except I cannot login to SuiteCRM. Each time I try, it gives the following error in red color.

“You have been logged out because your session has expired”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself after looking it up on Google. Since I am running php-fpm as `nginx` user therefore I had to change group from `apache` to `nginx` on `/var/lib/php/session`

```
chgrp nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

Comment: but I think good idea is to let php-fpm run as apache user becuase I noticed whenever php updates, it reverts back the permission to apache user